# How can I use a regex to match the user Id at the end of a url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My user show pages have URL's that look like this: "https://ee55715a523f4af8bae9f5467daf644d.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/users/1". I am trying to grab the user id from the end using a regex, and I know that this should work: [/\d+$/]. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#userplans").on('click', function(e) { 
    debugger;
    $.get("/fitness_plans", function(data) { 
        for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) { 
            const userId = $("#userId");
            debugger;
            if (data[i]["user_id"] === userId.innerText) { 
                $("#plans").append("<li>" + "Name: " + data[i]["workout_routine"]["name"] + "</li>") 
                    .append("<li>" + "Length(days): " + data[i]["duration"] + "</li>")
                    .append("<li>" + "Category: " + data[i]["workout_routine"]["category"] + "</li>") 
                    .append("<li>" + "Difficulty: " + data[i]["difficulty"] + "</li>") 
                    .append("<li>" + "Days per Week: " + data[i]["split_length"] + "</li>") 
            }
        }
    })
})
```

})
; 
When I enter the debugger and type "e.target.baseURI" I get the above url. However, when I type "e.target.baseURI[/\d+$/]" or "e.target.baseURI.match([/\d+$/])", I get undefined and null, respectively. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: alternate without regex `this.pathname.split('/').pop()`   or `e.target.baseURI.split('/').pop()`

Answer (score 0):

The code includes the quantifier `+` and boundary `$` characters within the [character set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets), use `/\d+$/` without surrounding brackets (character set)

```
"https://ee55715a523f4af8bae9f5467daf644d.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/users/1"
.match(/\d+$/)
```

Comment: Great! Much appreciated!